# breaking from infinite loop

Tags: bash, loops, cat

I'm running this query in bash:

```
mkfifo resp
while true; do 
    sudo nc -l -p 80 < resp |
    (cat & echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nhello :)" > resp) ||
    break; 
done
```

However when I <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, nothing happens, and the terminal locks up.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure it's relevant, but you either need to end the first two lines of your loop body with a backslash, or move the pipe/or operators up to the end of the previous line. Currently, you have 3 separate new-line-terminated commands, not a list containing a pipeline and the `break` command.

Comment: `nc` can use either `-l` or `-p`, but not both. Can you describe what this program is supposed to do?

Comment: @chepner That depends solely on the flavour of nc/netcat (BSD vs. linux). The opposite is frequently required

Comment: I see the prohibition in the man pages on both Linux and BSD (Mac OS X) systems.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fntNgc1T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot recreate this in my environment (RHEL)--CTRL-C works fine for me on this.  After your terminal locks up, I would open a new one and use `strace -p` to see at what's happening.

I think that there are some issues with the command setup in general, though.

First is that you're backgrounding `cat` in the subshell.  [Doing this makes the `stdin` of the `cat` command `/dev/null`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists), rather than the output of `nc` that you're piping into the subshell.  You can see the difference by comparing the output of this:

```
#! /bin/bash
# doesn't print yay
while true; do
    echo yay |
    (cat & false) ||
    break
done
```

with this:

```
#! /bin/bash
# does print yay
while true; do
    echo yay |
    (cat ; false) ||
    break
done
```

Also, I'm not clear on if this is intentional or not, but the break condition of your loop in general is based on the exit code of the subshell, which in turn will be the exit code of `echo`, which will always succeed, so the loop in general is infinite.  You can see this by replacing `false` in one of the above with an `echo`:

```
#! /bin/bash
while true; do
    echo yay |
    (cat & echo test) ||
    break
done
```

And, as @chepner pointed out, your usage of `nc` in general is also incorrect.  Per its manpage:

```
-l      Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection rather than initiate a connection to a remote host.  It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -p, -s, or -z options.
```

This is actually causing your `nc` command to do nothing at all (no output, just sit there).  You can see this by running `mkfifo resp ; nc -l -p 80 < resp` in one shell as root and then running `echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nhello :)" > resp` in another shell as root.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hehe, I approve your answer. Clearly you are very proud of attention to detail and I respect that. I've just spent the last 20 minutes playing with the resulting epiphany you've given me regarding bash. http://pastebin.com/fntNgc1T

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the sudo. Have you tried removing sudo from the script and sudoing the entire script?

Have you tried ctrl-Z and ps a to see what is holding it up?